# How do I add a new column with a repeated value per group based on condition in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

This is an example DataFrame.

```
RootProduct | Product | Value
    A           A        1  
    A           B        2   
    A           C        3
    D           D        4
    D           E        5
```

How can I add a fourth column, repeating the value present in the `Value` column when `RootProduct == Product` grouped by `RootProduct`?

This would result in the following DataFrame

```
RootProduct | Product | Value  | RootValue
    A           A        1          1
    A           B        2          1
    A           C        3          1 
    D           D        4          4 
    D           E        5          4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idea is compare both columns by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and then create `Series` by index with `Product` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), so possible use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by column `RootProduct`:

```
s = df[df['RootProduct'].eq(df['Product'])].set_index('Product')['Value']
df['RootValue'] = df['RootProduct'].map(s)
print (df)
  RootProduct Product  Value  RootValue
0           A       A      1          1
1           A       B      2          1
2           A       C      3          1
3           D       D      4          4
4           D       E      5          4
```

Detail of `Series`:

```
print (s)
Product
A    1
D    4
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Wow, this works perfectly. You just spared me a big headache!

Comment: what's the advantage of using `.eq()` instead of `==`? thanks

Comment: @politicalscientist -  If use boolean indexing with more mask not necessary `()`, so it means less typing `()` >= better readable